# How to copy big data over network?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, networking, rsync

I have a HP Microserver gen 8 with Centos 7 and only one hard disk in the bay area, 2 TB, mounted as NTFS.

I'm trying to copy files (about 100GB at once) over network from local.

I've tried with the following:

- via `Samba`
- via `SCP`
- via `Rsync`

Common issues along the way for this methods are usually with this error messages:

- System is read-only with I\O error (I've replaced the hard disk, because more likely it's causing this issue, not sure though)
- Disk is full (this just saw, and I was using `Samba`), Disk is 92% empty.
- mkstemp failed operation not permitted

So I'm thinking maybe there's a better way to copy big data; is there?

Also, i just tried to do this:

`rsync -rvz -e "ssh" * abude@192.168.0.106:/folder`

and I got this error:

```
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 16385 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/folder/movie.mkv": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(322) [receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (490 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Torrent answer couldn't be the only valid way to copy this much of data; I need a Linux based solution, without torrent.

--

**Update:**

After @zeppelin suggested to try one big file instead of many 4-5GB files, i've made one big archive using: `tar -zcvf movies.tar.gz *`

once i had the archive:

```
ls -alh movies.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r--  1 Abude  staff    77G Nov 11 13:54 movies.tar.gz
```

I did the `rsync` and got the following issue:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' --progress movies.tar.gz abude@192.168.0.106:/nas/media
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 19: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
building file list ... 
1 file to consider
movies.tar.gz
 82671089587 100%   25.36MB/s    0:51:49 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)
rsync: mkstemp "/nas/media/.movies.tar.gz.ezRUOM" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 82698841857 bytes  received 42 bytes  26586993.06 bytes/sec
total size is 82671089587  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Comment: You surely meant NTFS, no? Because FAT32 does not support bigger volumes than 32GB AFAIK.

Comment: Actually, FAT32 only supports filesizes up to 4 GB.

Comment: @pfnuesel I meant volume size, not a single file size.

Comment: @pfnuesel see update please

Comment: Is there anything relevant in `dmesg` output on sending or receiving machine?

Comment: @AndreasWiese No, no specific messages to this issue

Comment: I agree with [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322195/135943); `rsync` is the best solution.

Comment: @Wildcard i agree, but it's giving errors, so it's not a valid solution after all .

Comment: That you are getting errors is exactly why you should definitely stick with rsync (because it takes errors, & resumes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

The permission error (below) boiled down to removing the '-a' (--archive) flag from the *rsync* command, to prevent it from trying to preserve ownership and permissions on the files copied.

After doing the local 'dd' test, a low-level IO error was detected, probably caused by a faulty disk, resulting in a filesystem corruption.

---

> Operation not permitted (1)

The last error you see is a most probably simple permission issue, i.e. user 'abude' just does not have a write access to */nas/media/*),
try making this folder public writeable:

```
 chmod a+rwx /nas/media
```

and repeat your rsync command.

------- (disregard below, as OP is using a NTFS partition now) -----

Based on this:

> I have a HP Microserver gen 8 with Centos 7 and only one hard disk in the >bay area, 2 TB, mounted as **fat32**.

...

> rsync: write failed on "/folder/**movie.mkv**": Input/output error (5)
>   rsync error: error in file IO **(code 11) at receiver.c(322)** >>[receiver=3.0.9]

and your later comment

> @GMaster **any file under ~4GB has no errors**. i even can push this number 
>   to about 8-10GB but not sure though. – Abude 8 hours ago

I assume is that the problem you have it that you try to *rsync* (at least some) 4GB+ files to the FAT32 filesystem, which is not possible to do, as this is hard limit on the file size for FAT32.

> Maximum file size 2^32 minus 1 bytes

(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938937.aspx)

So *rsync* reports you a file IO error:

```
11     Error in file I/O
```

(https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

The options you have are:

- Exclude those large files from the sync with *--max-size=SIZE* rsync
  option (and later handle them manually in some way)
- Split them into smaller pieces (i.e. with *find* and *split*)
- Convert your filesystem to NTFS or Ext4 e.t.c. (e.g. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/303091/convert-fat32-partition-to-ntfs-without-data-loss)

Comment: did you read my question? i've mentioned that i have NTFS filesystem.

Comment: @Abude, ahh, I see, sorry :) Would you please strikeout (or otherwise remove) the original _mounted as fat32_ reference, then (as it is quite confusing).

Comment: Also does you comment on files >4GB still apply ?
What if you try to create a dummy 5GB file directly on the remote machine , like that: dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G count=5 > /mnt/mydisk/dummy.data ?

Comment: Files under ~8GB most likely will successfully finish, but with size increasing it could fail at any time.

Comment: Ok, but what if you try to create a really big file inplace with dd, say 32G in size? (to rule out a local issue)

Comment: Also you better use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/zero (as otherwise it will create a sparse file w/o doing much real IO)

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: See my update. It looks like you have a permission issue now.

Comment: Not the issue, because both /nas and /nas/media have 777

Comment: Hmm,  maybe it is a read-only mount? If you ssh as abuse and try to create file in /nas/media by hand, e.g. touch /nas/media/test, will it work for you? Another thing to check is extended ACLs,  with: getfacl /nas/media.

Comment: Also please check if SELinux is enabled with: sestatus (it might be preventing rsync from accessing it even if basic permissions are valid)

Comment: If you find the SELinux is enabled, please try to disable it as described here http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/, and give rsync a try once again.

Comment: yes i can create file with my user, Selinux was enabled and i've disabled it, and when i tried `rsync` again gave me the same error not permitted...

Comment: Ok, and if you try to _rsync_ individual small file (i.e. just a few kb), will you get exactly the same error as with your 32GB file ? 

Also please try to _scp_ the same file (to see if there will be the same error as for rsync).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48386/discussion-between-abude-and-zeppelin).

Answer (score 6):

To copy big chunks of data, a private torrent may be subjectively speaking one of the best choices.

This is not a place to make a tutorial of torrenting though.

You may look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33597/bittorrent-for-beginners-share-large-files-using-your-own-private-tracker/) for example or look up something like:

> How to create a private torrent

Comment: Despite your update, torrent sounds like a pretty valid solution. Having had to setup synchronization towards several Samba servers, I remember implementing some btsync puppet class, way easier to automate than any rsync-based cuisine.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` is the best solution. I recommend you remove the `-z` so that compression is skipped. Compression could be taking up extra disk space for temporary compressed files. So you should be using:

`rsync -av -e "ssh" * abude@192.168.0.106:/folder`

Comment: even if compression takes extra space, i have 92% free on the disk, so this is irrelevant, when i tried the `rsync` method i got the error from the question above.

Comment: What happens when you try to rsync a single file of small size, say 10MB? Do you get the same erro?

Comment: @GMaster, shouldn't that just be `rsync -av ./ abude@192.168.0.106:/folder`?

Comment: `*` works fine as well. I tried it just now.

Comment: @GMaster any file under ~4GB has no errors. i even can push this number to about 8-10GB but not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a local or otherwise secure network, you can transmit the data directly with `netcat` or `nc` depending on your distro.

On the target machine:

```
nc -l 0.0.0.0 45999 | tar -xz
```

On the source machine:

```
tar -cz the_files_or_folder | nc <target IP> 45999
```

This will tar and compress all the desired files and directly pipe them (unencrypted hence the local or secure network) to the target machine over TCP, on the receiving side `nc` will be listening and pipe them to tar to decompress and unarchive. You can remove the `z` argument on **both** sending and receiving `tar` commands to omit compression and send the data as is.

Also on the target machine IP `0.0.0.0` will listen on all interfaces, this can be a bit more insecure if you have other interfaces, to avoid this just replace for the desired IP reachable by the sending machine.

Comment: One issue with this is if the connection gets broekn, you have to transfer everything again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(322)
1. is /folder writable for you?

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (490 bytes received so far) [sender]
2. SSH dropped. can you ssh in? keyless or pw?

You said "I'm trying to copy files (about 100GB at once) over network from local."  Hope I didnt' read it wrong.  Target IP is non-routable IP (192.168.0.106)?  May be you are on VPN.

```
rsync -avr * user@<remoteIP>:/folder
```

use --bwlimit to 'slow it down' if you get dropped from connection.
use --partial to resume interrupted attempts

Comment: The commands in my question are working files for files under 8GB. not connectivity issue. thx

Answer (score 0):

Set up an FTP server on the machine with the data. You only have to run it as long as it takes to download the file, then you can shut it down. You could use a tool like wget to fetch it. That way if the download is interrupted it can be resumed without losing any time.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use dd over network.`dd if=/dev/sda | ssh username@servername.net "dd of=/dev/sdb"`
This makes a copy of SDA to sdb

Comment: hello, what do you mean by copy of sda to sdb? i don't want a perfect copy, files are just part of the partition on local machine.

Comment: The dd command generate an exact copy of `if`. So if you try and if it works you can move the file and do want is to do

Comment: Sledgehammer, please meet nut.

Comment: This is not what was asked (copy files, not copy a disk image). It won't work since a normal user can't write to `/dev/sdb`. Even if it did what was asked, it would be slow and brittle because of the use of `dd`.

Comment: Oh sorry, in my way you can copy 100GB of Data (files or whatever). It is slow but it works